# "Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly" when trying to start MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, windows-7, xampp

I'm using Windows 7 and running XAMPP MySQL SVC service. I'm seeing the following error:

> Windows could not start the Mysql service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Also true for WCF windows services that produce the same error.

Comment: What makes you think that this problem is related to PHP after all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Examine error log (start eventvwr.msc). MySQL typically writes something to the Application log.

In very rare cases it does not write anything (I'm only aware of one particular bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56821, where services did not work at all). There is also error log file, normally named .err in the data directory that has the same info as written to windows error log.

Answer (score 36):

You need to:

1. stop the MySQL service:
2. Open `mysql path\data`
3. Remove both `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`.
4. Restart the service

Comment: This really isn't a good solution as it will delete most (if not all) tables from your database.

Comment: This worked for me and my database tables didn't got got deleted.

Comment: This worked for me, and no data loss. The files are recreated on restart. on Windows the delete files is at ProgramData. I don't know the reason.

Comment: Very helpfull answer.... 
This worked for me too and database tables didn't got got deleted

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I am using mysql 5.6.11. 
To solve this problem I had to change *my-default.ini* file in *mysql-5.6.11-win32* folder
So I just pasted the following lines under line [mysqld]

```
basedir="D:\mysql-5.6.11-win32\"
datadir="D:\mysql-5.6.11-win32\data\"
port=3306
server-id=1
bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

Options basedir and datadir need to be modified for mysql location.

Comment: I added drive letter `basedir = "H:/xampp/mysql" `
`datadir = "H:/xampp/mysql/data"` and it worked

Comment: I had to remove the "port=3306", did not work with it. Now is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to check

```
innodb_data_home_dir = <your_directory_location>
innodb_log_group_home_dir = <your_directory_location>
```

on my.ini files. Wrong set value for these two variable make mysql process terminated and produce error `1067`. Also check `eventvwr.msc` and `mysql_error.log` for detail error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I was confused with @Vladislav's answer and couldn't seem to find the solution from that. Of course, my problem may not be exactly the same as I encountered the problem when trying to upgrade XAMPP, but it also gave the same **Error 1067** message.

With further search I found this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/214435/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-install-mysql-on

The answer from that is straightforward, that is, to completely **clean up the folder**, which doesn't always happen. As in regards to XAMPP, I guess I backed up the necessary files first (**data folder** from mysql folder and the **htdocs folder**). Uninstall XAMPP. Check the xampp folder for any content that remains and delete everything. You may want to reboot afterwards, just in case. Then reinstall XAMPP. Copy the backed-up folders back to their respective places, and hopefully, mySql will work again in XAMPP.

This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. After analysing log reports via **eventvwr.msc** I found, that logging files were placed in folder which requires admin rights to update, so files cannot be created and install and startup process could not proceed.

So checking eventlog was very usefull.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan! You saved the day! In my service, the logon user for the service was NETWORK. Seems this user does not have permissions to write to the disk where it needed. The event viewer showed this line. "Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\XXX.lower-test" I just changed the logon user to Logon as local system account and spoof... it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem from time to time, and when I do, I have been able to solve it by using a backup of the database folder(s) that give the problem.

When you check your 'Event Viewer > Windows Log > Application', if you see an error:

`InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace [database]/[table] uses space ID: 59 at filepath: .\[database]\[table].ibd. Cannot open tablespace [different db]/[different table] which uses space ID: 59 at filepath: .\[different db]/[different table].ibd`

Then what works for me, is delete the first mentioned [database] folder in your MySQL data directory, and copy the backup of that database folder to where it was previously.

Then start MySQL, and it starts again for me, without this 1067 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had practically the same problem. in the log file I found this:

```
110903  9:09:39  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
110903  9:09:40 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect key file for table 'user'; try to repair it
```

Apparently the user table has been corrupted. I replaced it with another copy (user.frm ; user.MYD ; user.MYI in mysql\data\mysql)
and thats works for me.

ps: am using xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Search and destroy (or move cautiously) any my.ini files (windows or program files), which is affecting the mysql service failure. also check port 3306 is used by using either netstat or portqry tool. this should help. Also if there is a file system issue you can run check disk.

Answer (score 0):

I just went throught same issue and I solved it the following way.
1 - found the .err file which logs all mysql issues, in win7, located under programData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\ 
2 - Check the last entries from the file and, in my case, I found the error was coming from a flag (audit-log) that I set to "true" from the workbench interface the day before!
3 - went into the my.ini file, and removed audit-log=ON.
4 - launched mysql service and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, and what worked for me is in [THIS OTHER ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37689969/1920145).

I didn't replicated it here because it is [NOT A CORRECT THING TO DO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104231/305276).

Basically is a re-install being sure to delete everything very well and using 32 bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I checked the error logs: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\inf3rno-PC.err`. According to them

```
170208  1:06:25 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete

170208  1:10:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170208  1:10:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170208  1:10:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
170208  1:10:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
170208  1:10:44  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
170208  1:10:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170208  1:10:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170208  1:10:44 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: INNODB
170208  1:10:44 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I think the important part here

```
170208  1:10:44  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
```

I changed the `TMP` and `TEMP` env variables from `C:\Windows\Temp` to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` yesterday, because I was unable to compress a directory and according to many post the solution is that. Now compression works, but mysql and apparently nod32 complains that they cannot create temporary files...

I added `tmpdir=c:/server/mytmp` to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini`. And after that started the service again with services.msc. It is okay now.

So this can be a possible cause as well. I strongly suggest to everybody encountering this problem to check the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I use install file to repair. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

please check the space available on drive where the db is stored. in my case it was stopped the service due to less space on drive.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for the problem. This worked for me

Right click on Service -> Properties -> Log on as system account.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [this article](https://www.minitool.com/news/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly.html) my problem has been solved.

I followed the below steps.

1. Launch the Run dialog, input Regedit and click Enter.
2. After opening the Registry Editor window, head to the path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Services
3. Find the service that has the error 1067 from the list (Here, we take the MariaDB service as an example). Right-click on it, click Export to save it to the desktop or any place, name it MariaDB and click Save. We do this process is to create a backup for the service.
4. Then right-click on the service and choose Delete to remove it from the services list.
5. Run Command Prompt with administrative rights, input sfc /scannow, and press Enter to perform a scan for your Windows system.
6. Restart your computer. Then, find the backup of the registry key you have saved, right-click on it and choose Merge.
7. Open the Services window via the Windows search bar, right-click on the service and click Start.(If you don't see your service yet there, restart your computer after merge once again)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

- Stop the MySQL service.
- Copy and replace folder `"mysql"` from    `"C:\xampp\mysql\backup"`
  to `"C:\xampp\mysql\data"`.

  100% working

Answer (score -1):

error reason running mysql in XAMPP server in win8 thats hapen for me.

if error display when you install MariaDB First Stop MySql in XAMPP

and install MariaDB there is not problem now...have a nice day...