# configuration of mysql server installation failed OR can't start the service

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm installing mysql server 5.6 but when it comes to installing configuration it sucks on attempting to start service
and when I cancel and try to start from Services it says:
Error 1067: The program terminated unexpectedly.

and here's my .err:

```
2014-03-17 20:42:10 1372 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-03-17 20:42:10 fe0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-03-17 20:42:10 1372 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-03-17 20:42:10 1372 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-03-17 20:42:10 1372 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-03-17 20:42:10 1372 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-03-17 20:42:10 1372 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 39.0M
2014-03-17 20:42:10 1372 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-03-17 20:42:10 1372 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-03-17 20:42:10 fe0  InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-03-17 20:42:10 1372 [ERROR] InnoDB: File .\ib_logfile0: 'aio read' returned OS     error 187. Cannot continue operation
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758844/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-start-mysql

Answer (score 24):

solution:

add this line to config file (my.ini in programData...)

```
innodb_flush_method=normal
```

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28913

Comment: Friggin' bug, thanks for this solution! I was moving my data folder to an external drive of 3 TB, and that didn't work without above extra setting (because of >2TB, see the bug-link).

Comment: It only worked for me if added that line under `innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50`

Comment: Thank you...I lost an hour for this on a fresh easyPHP installation!