# UwAmp : Mysql server not starting

Tags: mysql, uwamp

Mysql Server stop working after 2 seconds (fresh install of uwamp)

Uwamp version 3.1 started with Administrator rights on windows 8.1 pro 64 bits.

Here is the Mysql log :

```
2016-05-05T21:13:23.906126Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-05-05T21:13:23.907126Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2016-05-05T21:13:23.907126Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2016-05-05T21:13:23.907126Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2016-05-05T21:13:23.907126Z 0 [Note] E:\www\UwAmp\bin\database\mysql-5.7.11\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.11) starting as process 3280 ...
2016-05-05T21:13:23.932127Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open shared library 'E:\www\UwAmp\bin\database\mysql-5.7.11\lib\plugin\keyring_file.dll' (errno: 126 Le module spécifié est introuvable.)
2016-05-05T21:13:23.936127Z 0 [ERROR] Couldn't load plugin named 'keyring_file' with soname 'keyring_file.dll'.
2016-05-05T21:13:23.939127Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-05-05T21:13:23.941128Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-05-05T21:13:23.945128Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-05-05T21:13:23.947127Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-05-05T21:13:23.949128Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-05-05T21:13:23.950128Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-05-05T21:13:24.059136Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-05-05T21:13:24.074137Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-05-05T21:13:24.143139Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
2016-05-05T21:13:24.684140Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
2016-05-05T21:13:25.249173Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
2016-05-05T21:13:25.251203Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2016-05-05T21:13:25.255204Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File .\ib_logfile101: 'aio write' returned OS error 187. Cannot continue operation
2016-05-05T21:13:25.258204Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I have no problem with the version 3.0.2

Thank you for your help

Comment: `Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.` and `'aio write' returned OS error 187.` seem to be the central error messages worth Googling.

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of: [mysql server not starting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461872/configuration-of-mysql-server-installation-failed-or-cant-start-the-service).  It seemed like adding "innodb_flush_method=normal" to the my.ini config file fixed the issue for this person which also was related to the same logfile.  This was a reported bug back in 2007 but it seems like people were still encountering this error all the way up to 2014.