# Database initialization failed when installing MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, initialization, failed-installation

Database initialization failed when trying to install MySQL on windows 10, I have very limited knowledge about MySQL. I have attached pics, could you please help?

[image]

Logs:

[image]

Comment: could you post the log? you might need to click the "log" tab (in your picture) or look for log file in your disk

Comment: I just added a screen caption of the log, thank you.

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469514/3706717 ?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall mySQL in programfiles, programfiles(x86), programData.

Restart your computer and redo the process allover, click 'NO' to autoupdate when you launch the installer.