# MySQL Service Failed to Start

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with starting MySQL Service. I reinstalled MySQL in my PC and copied the "data" folder of my backup inside the newly installed MySQL Server folder. When I start MySQL in local services, it displays error message: "Could not start the MySql service on local Computer Error 1067: The process terminited unexpectedly". How can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried to google for a fix? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758844/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-start-mysql

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/214435/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-install-mysql-o