# Error 1067 when starting up MySQL in services

Tags: mysql, database, windows, innodb

When i start my mysql service it shows this:

[image]

and this shows up in my cmd

[image]

Please help i've been stuck for 2 hours nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Not sure if it'll help but what happens when you
1. Right click the start button.
2. Go to Computer Management
3. Under Services and Applications > Services
4. Find the mysql process
5. Right click and start?

Helped me start it on Windows a little while back

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758844/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-start-mysql

Comment: Did you recently change anything in my.cnf?

Comment: What value do you have for `innodb_flush_method`?

Comment: Is it Windows 10?  What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't do windows MySQL, but I do both Windows and MySQL, so here's my 2 cents worth:

Your system says it can not create/write to a file and it gives a specific location where it intends to create a "pid" file, but can not do so.

The PID file is where MySQL will store it's "I'm running" information, without that it will never run. So find out why it can not write that file at that location and you will probably unlock your next level.

Or install in Linux, which would be *my* advice. Even a virtualized linux can easily run mysql with a simple install command. Virtualbox, VMware ... (sorry, had to.)